Green's Theorem Problem, Answer is not matching with textbook.
Verify Green's Theorem to evaluate the line integral
$$ \oint_C (2y^2 \, dx + 3x \, dy), $$
where (C) is the boundary of the closed region bounded by $(y = x)$ and $(y = x^2)$. For this problem, the answer is $(-\frac{7}{30})$.
For another similar question, verify Green's Theorem for the line integral
$$ \oint_C \left[(xy + y^2) \, dx + x^2 \, dy \right], $$
where (C) is bounded by $(y = x)$ and $(y = x^2)$, and for this question, the answer is $(-\frac{1}{20})$.
For the first question, we are taking the $(y)$-variable limit from $(x) to (x^2)$, but in the second question, we are taking the $(y)$-variable limit from $(x^2) to (x)$ in order to match the textbook answer. Is there any problem with the textbook answer or in the calculation of the limit?

We can give you a much better answer if you show all the steps you  preformed.

Did they say how they want those curves to be oriented (clockwise, counterclockwise)?

Green's Theorem
Green's Theorem states that for a positively oriented, simple closed curve (C) enclosing a region (D),
$$ \oint_C (P \, dx + Q \, dy) = \iint_D \left( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right) \, dA. $$
First Line Integral
For the line integral
$$\oint_C (2y^2 \, dx + 3x \, dy), $$
where C is bounded by ${y = x}$ and $y = x^2$:
Identify $P$ and $Q$:
$P = 2y^2$,
$Q = 3x$
Compute the partial derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = 3$$and $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 4y$$
Set up the double integral:
$$\iint_D (3 - 4y) dA$$
$$$$
$$$$

$$$$
$$$$
Determine the limits of integration:

The region D is bounded by $y = x$ and $y = x^2$
For $x$ limits: $0 \leq x \leq 1$
For $y$ limits:$ x^2 \leq y \leq x$

Now, Evaluate the our integral
$$ 
   \iint_D (3 - 4y) \, dA = \int_0^1 \int_{x^2}^x (3 - 4y) \, dy \, dx
   $$
$$
   = \int_0^1 \left[ 3y - 2y^2 \right]_{x^2}^x \, dx$$
$$ = \int_0^1 \left( 3x - 2x^2 - (3x^2 - 2x^4) \right) \, dx$$
$$= \int_0^1 \left( 3x - 2x^2 - 3x^2 + 2x^4 \right) \, dx$$
$$= \int_0^1 \left( 3x - 5x^2 + 2x^4 \right) \, dx$$
$$ = \left[ \frac{3x^2}{2} - \frac{5x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{5} \right]_0^1$$
$$= \left( \frac{3}{2} - \frac{5}{3} + \frac{2}{5} \right)$$
$$= \frac{45 - 50 + 12}{30} = \frac{7}{30}$$
Value of integral is $(\frac{7}{30})$.
Second Line Integral
Similarly
$$ \oint_C \left[(xy + y^2) \, dx + x^2 \, dy \right], $$
where (C) is bounded by $y = x$and $y = x^2$:
Evaluate the double integral:
$$\iint_D (x - 2y) \, dA = \int_0^1 \int_{x^2}^x (x - 2y) \, dy \, dx$$
$$ = \int_0^1 \left[ xy - y^2 \right]_{x^2}^x \, dx$$
$$  = \int_0^1 \left( x^2 - x^2 - (x^3 - x^4) \right) \, dx$$
$$= \int_0^1 \left( - x^3 + x^4 \right) \, dx$$
$$= \left[ - \frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^5}{5} \right]_0^1$$
$$= \left( - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} \right)$$
$$ = \frac{ - 5 + 4}{20} = -\frac{1}{20}$$
This matches the given answer  $(-\frac{1}{20})$.

I get $\frac{45 - 50 + 12}{30}=\color{red}{+}\frac 7{30},.$

thanks @KurtG. i did mistake in calculation.

the formatting is really bad

okay I'll try to fix it @SineoftheTime

Why does OP's book claim it is $-\frac7{30},?$ Same hint I gave OP: orientation of the curve. Rather than writing such a long answer it is that you guys should focus on.
